# Application Loader CFBundleResourceSpecification and Application failed codesign verification errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, loader

While using Application Loader to submit my application, I receive 2 errors:

`1) Info.plist does not containt a CFBundleResourceSpecification
2) Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.`

For the latter, I am a registered paying developer that has created a distribution certificate. That cert has been installed as has the intermediate cert. I've created a Distribution Provisioning Profile as well. It has been downloaded and installed into xCode.

Inside xCode I have done the following

- Created a distribution configuration
- In that configuration for the project settings, set the code signing to be the above mentioned provisioning profile
- In that configuration for the edit project target settings, set the code signing to be the above mentioned provisioning profile
- Set the bundle identifier to the correct reverse lookup fqd

Can anyone push me in the right direction, does it sound like I have overlooked something in this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DEE Duh Dee...

I had to build a device version, not a simulator version. Sorry to waste your time peoples.